# Специализация функций шаблонных классов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

К примеру есть шаблонный класс вектор.

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
class vector
{
..
}
```

Мне нужно перегрузить оператор умножения вектора на вектор только в трёхмерном пространстве. Пробовал так:

```
template<typename T, size_t D>
vector<T, 3>& vector<T, 3>::operator * (const vector<T, 3>& r_operand) const
{

}
```

Получаю ошибку.

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class vector<Type, 3u>'
```

Можно ли это делать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Если и можна, то вы не все `D` поменяли на `3` у вас вначале идёт D а потом 3. (в первой строчке перегрузки)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Частичной специализации функций в C++ не существует — такие вещи решаются перегрузкой. Почти всегда этого достаточно, если же нет, то заводят фиктивные структуры, которые затем и специализируют.

Ваша задача решается элементарной перегрузкой с примесью небольшой шаблонной магии:

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
class vector
{
public:

    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<D == 3, void>::type>
    vector<T, 3> operator * (const vector<T, 3>& rhs)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Для C++14 запись может быть несколько сокращена:

```
template<typename = std::enable_if_t<D == 3, void>>
vector<T, 3> operator * (const vector<T, 3>& rhs)
{
    return *this;
}
```

Но, в целом, если для трёх измерений у Вас отличается обработка, то, возможно, имеет смысл специализировать весь класс, т.к. если отличия не только в одной операции, то это очень быстро станет неуправляемым.

---

Если надо вне класса определение вынести:

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
class vector
{
public:

    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<D == 3, void>::type>
    vector<T, 3> operator * (const vector<T, 3>& rhs);
};

template <typename T, size_t D>
template<typename>
vector<T, 3> vector<T, D>::operator * (const vector<T, 3>& rhs)
{
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: В записи для C++11 Вы не пропустили возвращаемое значение `vector<T, 3>`?

Comment: И как в таком случае вынести реализацию функции за пределы определения класса?

Comment: @Gordory, обновил ответ.

Comment: Вроде только понял как это работает - а оно не собирается.
Выдает `default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'vector<Type, 3u> vector<Type, Dim>::operator*(const vector<Type, 3u>&)'
 vector<Type, 3> vector<Type, Dim>::operator * (const vector<Type, 3>& r_operand)`

Comment: @Gordory, перестарался я немного. Забирайте.

Comment: Ох, а как теперь `template<typename>` работает? Этот typename связывается с определенным выше `typename = std::enable_if<D == 3, vector<T, 3>`?

Comment: @Gordory, `typename` это просто безымянный параметры шаблона. Можно было бы написать `typename MeTheName` — ничего бы не поменялось. А параметры по умолчанию работают так же, как с аргументами функции: указывать их нужно(и можно) лишь в декларации, а в определении просто указываем количество параметров с именами(опционально). Таким образом у нас есть шаблонная функция с одним безымянным параметром, который по умолчанию инициализируется тем выражением, что описано в декларации.

Answer (score 4):

Если не хочется копировать все тело вектора (при специализации), можно оформить оператор в качестве свободной функции, тогда можно специализировать оператор, независимо от специализации класса

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
class vector
{
public:
};


template<typename T, size_t D>
vector<T, D> operator * (const vector<T, D>&  l_operand,  const vector<T, D>& r_operand)
{
    ...
}

template<typename T>
vector<T, 3> operator * (const vector<T, 3>&  l_operand,  const vector<T, 3>& r_operand)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Что произойдет в случае если я попытаюсь вызвать эту функцию для, скажем, 4-мерного пространства? Чем инстанцируется шаблон? Хотелось бы чтобы при таком инстанцировании происходила ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Отвечаю на свой же вопрос. Можно просто описать сразу шаблон функции вне класса. В таком случае это даже не будет специализацией шаблона. `template<typename Type>
vector<Type, 3> operator * (const vector<Type, 3>& l_operand, const vector<Type, 3>& r_operand)`

Comment: @Gordory, это не Вы отвечаете на свой вопрос, это Вам Chorkov в своём ответе написал. Если нужна перегрузка только для 3 измерений, значит оставляете только для 3-х. Надо больше — добавляете дополнительные функции.

Comment: Вопрос, тем не менее, относительно частичной специализации функции КЛАССА остаётся в силе.

Comment: @ixSci да, я уже понял :)

Comment: @Gordory, частичной специализации **никаких** функций в C++ нет. Пользуйтесь перегрузкой.

Comment: @ixSci поясните для исходного примера? Как в таком случае пользуясь перегрузкой решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то специализировать шаблон функции частично нельзя.

Т.е. вам надо специализировать сам класс

```
template <typename T>
class Vector<T,3>
{
    ...
```

И уже в нем описывать свой оператор

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - сделать это возможно, примеры в интернете есть, народ даже проверяет специально, хотя часто в литературе написано, что нельзя.

Comment: @Gordory Ну тогда покажите, как - в чем проблемы?

Comment: я, по всей видимости, запутался.
В примерах была ПОЛНАЯ специализация. Вроде немного разобрался.